# Where do I have to save my own font?

Tags: fonts

### Please see my update at the end

---

I don't want to ask a xy-Question, so here comes the "hole" story:

I want to install a font, which isn't available on ctan.

(I guess it's necessary to install fonts and not able to just save something like the hole folder just where my .tex is saved)

This all takes place on macOS.

I guess the main error I get is:

Every time I run `sudo updmap-sys` I get:

```
updmap [ERROR]: The following map file(s) couldn't be found:
updmap [ERROR]:     fontname.map (in /usr/local/texlive/2017/texmf-config/web2c/updmap.cfg)
updmap [ERROR]: Did you run mktexlsr?
```

But I did run:

```
sudo -H mktexlsr
sudo -H updmap-sys --enable Map fontname.map
```

I'm unsure where to save the new files, which are:

I got an own font which came in this folder structure:

```
filename
-fonts
--map
---dvips
----universityname
-----fontname
------fontname.map
--tfm
---universityname
----fontname
-----*several .tfm-files*
--type1
---universityname
----fontname
-----*several .pfb-files*
--vf
---universityname
----fontname
-----*several .vf-files*
-ls-R
-tex
--latex
---universityname
----fontname
-----8runiversityname.fd
-----fontname.sty
-----ot1universityname.fd
-----t1universityname.fd
-----ts1universityname.fd
```

I **guess** my questions are:

1. Is it right to save everything in "texmf-local" and not in "2017" (the error I get searches in "2017")
2. Do I keep the folder "universityname"?
3. Do I save the folder "universityname" (or "fontname") in "local" or on the same level as "local"?
4. What to do with my folder "map"?

my usr/local/texlive contained:

```
2017
-texmf-config
--web2c
---updmap.cfg
texmf-local
-dvips
--local
-fonts
--source
---local
--tfm
---local
--type1
---local
--vf
---local
-ls-R
-tex
--latex
---local
--plain
---local
```

and some other files...

---

**UPDATE:**

The file `filename/tex/latex/universityname/fontname/fontname.sty` contains:

```
\NeedsTeXFormat{LaTeX2e}%
\ProvidesPackage{fontname}[2017/04/16 v1.0 âFF]%
\RequirePackage{textcomp}%
\RequirePackage{xkeyval}%
\define@key{fontname.sty}{scaled}[1.0]%
{%
  \def\MF@universityname@scale{#1}%
}%
\define@key{fontname.sty}{leading}[1.0]%
{%
  \linespread{#1}%
}%
\ExecuteOptionsX{scaled}%
\ProcessOptionsX\relax%
\renewcommand*{\rmdefault}{universityname}%
\newcommand\Meta{\fontfamily{universityname}\fontseries{m}\fontshape{n}\selectfont}%
\endinput%
```

---

**UPDATE 2:**

The current "error" produced by

```
sudo -H updmap-sys --enable Map fontname.map
```

I get is:

```
/usr/local/texlive/2017/texmf-config/web2c/updmap.cfg unchanged. Map files not recreated.
```

---

**UPDATE 3:**

Trying to use `\usepackage{fontname}` I get

```
! Font T1/cmss/m/n/4=ecss0400 at 4.0pt not loadable: Metric (TFM) file not found.
```

---

**UPDATE 4:**

Right now the font can be used **without** `\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}`. But the following code produces `! Font T1/cmss/m/n/4=ecss0400 at 4.0pt not loadable: Metric (TFM) file not found`

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{fontname}

\begin{document}

\begin{frame}
Test
\end{frame}

\end{document}
```

Comment: You should merge the contents of your `filename` directory into `/usr/local/texlive/texmf-local/`.  “Merge” means: (1) for every subdirectory of your directory that already exists in the merged-into directory by the same name, merge its contents (defined recursively) into the already existent directory; (2) copy, along with its contents, any subdirectory that doesn’t already exist in the merged-into directory.  Then run `sudo mktexlsr`.

Comment: @GuM thanks for your answer. I did so. But I'm unsure how to merge. Please see my Questions in the middle.

Comment: It would also help to check the contents of your `filename/tex/latex/universityname/fontname/fontname.sty` file, if you are allowed to post them.

Comment: @GuM please see my update.

Comment: Let’s say that your system already has a path to `/usr/local/texlive/texmf-local/fonts/tfm/`, with all directories up to and including `tfm/` already in place: then, from within the `filename` directory issue `cp -R fonts/tfm/universityname /usr/local/texlive/texmf-local/fonts/tfm/`.  Let’s say, on the other hand, that `/usr/local/texlive/texmf-local/fonts/` does not contain a `map/` directory: then, always from within the `filename` directory issue `cp -R fonts/map /usr/local/texlive/texmf-local/fonts/`.  And so on.

Comment: What counts is that the `.fd` files must all be of the form *`universityname.fd`, if the line that contains the `\renewcommand*{\rmdefault}{...}` actually reads `\renewcommand*{\rmdefault}{universityname}`.  For example, for `\renewcommand*{\rmdefault}{duckburguniversity}`, the files should be named `8rduckburguniversity.fd`, `ot1duckburguniversity.fd`, etc., and this is the case in your `filename` directory, isn’t it?

Comment: @GuM thanks so far. I copied everything, so that the folder "universityname" is on the same level as "local". The mentioned error is gone, but I still can't use the font.
(My .fd files are named correctly)

`sudo -H updmap-sys --enable Map fontname.map` produced `/usr/local/texlive/2017/texmf-config/web2c/updmap.cfg unchanged.  Map files not recreated.`

I guess that this is the next error

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/68262/discussion-between-gum-and-ben).